# Merge duplicate rows where fields are different

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, duplicates

These are my query results:

[image]

But I want to merge the MemberName column when the member is the same. But the values in the other columns still need to display separately. How can I make my report use the following format?

[image]

Comment: Please remove the image links and instead include a _minimal_ amount of sample data and the expected output as makes your question clear as to what you are after.  I'm counting 20 rows and a dozen columns in your source table, in small print, way to much information.

Comment: Any output table from sql query will be in first normal form(1NF) and the output you want is not in 1NF( merging the rows for specific columns). So i will suggest to take the output of sql server into xml and use xml as a source crystal report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Group for `SIno` at the lowest level, if you don't have one already. Suppress the header and footer of this group.

Then add this formula to the suppression logic for `SIno`, `Member Name`, and `Sanity Code`:

```
{SIno} = PREVIOUS({SIno})
```

---

After discussing your needs in the comments, I recommend the following: Set your report such that it doesn't have any borders, and instead have the background color alternate between white and gray. Group based on `SIno` if you haven't already, and set the background color to:

```
IF GROUPNUMBER MOD 2 = 0 THEN crWhite else crSilver
```

I do this all the time with my reports. It looks professional, and the customers understand it:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'm new in this crystal report thing. Can you please explain this more clearly. TIA.

Comment: @MDSaddamHossain - What part of the answer don't you understand? Creating Groups, Suppressing Sections, or Suppressing Fields?

Comment: Please check the link of image i attached, this is the present condition of my report, i have done everything just need to remove the blank rows from the first three columns. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Qu8B08k2phTmsyemxtck13VU0

Comment: @MDSaddamHossain That's not how Crystal Reports works. If you attempt to remove a row, you remove the entire row - including the data on it.

Comment: then how should i manage it? is there any way to solve this by changing the sql query i wrote? TIA